How could double damage be explained in-universe?
I'm creating a tabletop role-playing steampunk fantasy game. Within the game are elemental weapons and spells similar to the ones in Borderlands. One of the elements is Slag. An organism or structure coated in Slag takes double damage from all non-Slag sources. From a game mechanic (or Crunch) perspective, this is very simple to explain. But of course, people living within a fantasy world don't think in terms of damage numbers or health bars; those are just visual aids players have to see how effective combat is.
So if a person is coated in slag, what physically or magically happens to them so that an attack (say a gunshot or a punch) causes twice as much pain or injury to them? I have considered just doubling the kinetic energy that they receive, but I don't think there is a 1:1 correlation between kinetic energy and damage dealt. I'm also not sure if doubling kinetic energy actually makes sense without changing the mass or acceleration of the projectile.

Slagged characters are wasted. (See what I did there? Slag is a waste product.) Slaggy adventures get immunocompromised. Slagful armor gets corroded. Slagging weakens the bones. Slagging is lagging. Slag is a drag. Getting slagged, getting fragged. You get slagged, you get snagged. Covered in slag, weak as a hag. Getting slaggy makes you naggy. Slag makes one sag. Slaggy sword, draggy sword. Full of slag, strong as a rag. VTC as not about worldbuilding.

Not an answer, because it's facile, but if you've got magic in play, you don't really need additional explanation.  "Any damage received is doubled" makes as much sense as the Law of Threefold Return, or how a pin in a Voodoo doll causes harm.

@jdunlop Good stories explain how magic works and its limits, even if magic violates real-life physics. If a story has arbitrary, unexplained magic, it ruins any tension or buildup for conflict. A wizard can just clap their hands and any plot is instantly solved or unsolved. Look up Sanderson's Laws of Magic.

While it's true that magic which can solve any problem without effort or sacrifice ruins a story, arbitrariness doesn't really.  The rule is that slag is vulnerable to non-slag.  That IS the rule.  We argue about why gravity pulls you down, and whether gravity is exactly real - but gravitational attraction IS the rule.  Knowing why doesn't make stories about flight any more or less interesting.

@AlexP - despite disagreeing with the call for VTC - the Rhyming sentence was pure gold.

I agree with @AlexP, VTC:NAW. No criteria have been given to define a best answer and a single best answer isn't intrinsic to the question, violating the prohibitions in the [help/dont-ask]. I'm tempted to suggest this is a question asking for help scientifically rationalizing magic, but the simple truth is that you're not asking for help with a worldbuilding rule (something that frames the story), you're asking for help with an aesthetic, which is the story itself and prohibited in the [help/on-topic].

So people and things coated in Slag have a detriment of being more vulnerable to certain kinds of damage. Is there any benefit to being coated in Slug? Is it like a poison? Perhaps this would be clearer if I was more familiar with Borderlands.

@Jedediah  In point of fact, magic being arbitrary can easily add to the dramatic tension if done right.  (c.f. "Wild Magic")

I'm going to challenge your assertion that people in-universe won't know about damage numbers, etc.  They are certainly going to study the "laws of physics" in their own universe, and the constraints of your game mechanics will mean that there will be some pretty recognizable patterns to the world around them. Things always happening in fixed-size blocks of time, the number of hits a fighter can take being easily quantifiable, they'll be just as noticeable as quantum energy levels and Planck's Constant are in our universe. Maybe not everyone knows about them, but some people likely will.

@Jedediah hits the nail on the head.  Its limits and how it works are straightforward - all damage done to someone coated with magical Slag is doubled.  Plenty of magic systems work with no greater specification than that (see aforementioned voodoo dolls, threefold return).

If I coat my baseball bat in slag and hit you with it, does it hurt more as well? If so, then it's just a general catalyst/multiplier, and leaving it unexplained can make sense (we don't know why mana works the way it does either, we just know that it behaves in certain ways, which we can apply in ways that benefit us). If not, then you're arguing that slag somehow compromises organisms in a way that they don't get affected if you briefly hit them with a slag-covered item. Both answers to this question have interesting ramifications for your idea.

"I don't think there is a 1:1 correlation between kinetic energy and damage dealt" When you make statements like these, it becomes really important to evaluate what line of realism you're aiming for here. Too granular of an explanation will lead to overexposition of your world and lore, and will actively lessen the ability for imagination to take over. I don't know Pokémon internal anatomy and I don't need to know it for the purpose of enjoying the show and games. Charizard breathes fire and we're not trying to harness it as a free power source, so the mechanics are irrelevant.

Slag Isn't Real
Or, more accurately, it's less real.  Like the Nothing in the Neverending Story, it drains reality from the things around it.
There might be advantages to being less real - perhaps it numbs your pain.  Maybe you age slower.  Some magic might be easier, or more powerful.  But if you're about to be thwacked with a completely real club, being less real means you put up less resistance to that club swinging through the space you occupy.  You're still too real for that to work out for you.
Shedding the slag lets you become fully real again (all at once - or maybe gradually, if you've been slagged for awhile), so where's the harm in a little unreality?  Until someone swings a club at your head.
But how much exposure to slag does it take to compromise an object?  Does smashing a slagged object compromise the hammer you're smashing with?

The subsequent question is also whether coating a weapon in slag makes it do double damage to whoever receives the blow. Because either answer to that question is going to suggest different reasons for how it works.

@Flater One of the secret rules of magic (which slag apparently is) is that it can apply fairness to reactions, in ways actual physics does not.  Is it fair for slag-coated items to deal extra damage?

Is it fair that fire burns you? It's not about fairness, it's about equivalence. OP's description of how slag works implies that it connects two things and somehow alters the interaction that was already happening between these two things. Whether thing A or thing B gets coated before the other one wouldn't matter for that definition, but that's specifically what I'm trying to find out. Because if it does matter, then there's a deeper explanation about why it needs to first be applied to thing A and not thing B.

@Flater I don't mean to imply that you're not asking a useful and interesting question - I didn't feel qualified to really answer it (since I'm trying to keep my answer compatible with the sparse description of the asker).  But I'm suggesting it's possible slag doesn't work like fire, because fire obeys real physics, not magic.  (Magic, in an RPG, may bend to game balancing considerations in it's "fairness", for example - would it be easier to instantly speak a foreign language or stop someone's heart?  In D&D, for balance and fairness, it's not stopping their heart.)

My point is that there is contextual tension between the specifics of needing to cover an individual (including its effect of then physically being hit), and then leaving the ostensibly identical scenario of being hit with an item coated in it unspoken. I agree that you could leave it unspoken in general; but given OP's search for a realistic explanation, that would have to cover this scenario as well. It's a table-top roleplaying game, players are very likely to raise this question as part of the game mechanic. "No that doesn't work" is valid, I'm only suggesting to consider the question.

@Flater this question could be easily solved by deciding how long slag takes to reduce the reality of an object. If it is instant using a slag coated weapon might work. I would have problems breaking a wooden chair with a wooden club. However if the reality-loss makes the wood weaker as if it is rotten, I might be able to pull that off more easily. On the other hand The risk of damaging my club in the process would also increase. If slag needs some time to take full effect, coating a weapon in slag is a bad idea and you instead should throw it in your opponents face.

@datacube: That's the question I'm prompting to be considered. I wasn't offering an answer, I was pointing out that it would be good to think about the question.

Slag is temporal detritus that works as entropy accelerator. It is what happens to tachyons (particles of time) that decayed. In effect, Slag doubles any entropy event that occurs within it. Shoot a bullet through Slag, Slag makes it seem like the bullet passed twice through the same spot, hitting the target twice. There is just one bullet, but it seemed to have gone back in time after it hit, and strike again nanosecond later. Same happens to damage from heat, cuts, poison, acid, etc, anything that causes entropy seem to happen twice, doubling on itself. The sole exception should be freezing: since Ice damage decreases entropy, Slag makes it less effective not more.

Now that's good pseudo-science.

Damage from cold should be reduced, but damage from freezing is physical trauma and should (by this logic) also be increased. Unless you're saying that you'd only get amorphous ice, or something, but that doesn't jive with entropy doubling.

Now the question: If you have two impacts in a fraction of a second after each other at the same spot, is that only double damage or even more? Like the first hit applies stress to the point and before it has a chance to return to the initial state, even more stress is applied to exact the same spot

@wizzwizz4, if damage from cold is reduced, then damage from freezing and ice would not occur, unless the temperature is twice lower than freezing temp (say minus 200 Celsius for water)

@Zibelas I think we should conclude it is double damage on average, not absolutely always, because it would depend on the energy of the thing that causes the damage, and the durability of what it is damaging. For example, damage from a bullet to flesh would be more than doubled (because flesh barely resists bullets anyway), while damage from a punch would be less than doubled (because human flesh is pretty resistant to punches, and the second punch can't do much more than the first already did).

@GoingDurden If you want to mess around with temperature, absolute zero is the natural point to use (-200°C is immersion-breaking levels of arbitrary) – but also, if you mess around with one temperature then you mess around with all temperatures, and that'd near-instantly kill a human.

@wizzwizz4, I assumed OP's world being a tabletop RPG, arbitrarily precise mathematical answers like that are not only allowed but encouraged. RPGs do not follow real physics, but roll-able values where things like 2xDamage or +15 Coldness somehow make sense, so why not -200C, or even -2 Freezyness? TRPGs by design break immersion like this.

Slag embrittles everything
When embrittled, materials are more likely to take damage. There are many ways that Slag could cause embrittlement, such as the Rehbinder effect.
In general, increasing damage doesn't need to make all incoming attacks "more powerful" somehow, it just needs make the target more damageable.

Slag is like Flubber.  A chemical or magical substance with a large amount of energy bound up in it that can be released under the right circumstances.
So, just like fire damage can be amplified if the target is coated in oil due to the release of stored energy, damage to a target coated in slag is amplified.
The difference is that releasing the energy in slag can be triggered by a wide variety of things, not just heat.
One thing you'll need to decide is if the energy release feedback loop from slag is positive, in which case triggering it will release all the energy, consuming the slag entirely, or negative, in which case the reaction will peter out and leave some amount of slag unconsumed.
This does mean slag can be used as a power source for all kinds of fantastical devices though.

It causes radiation damage
Slag is a kinetically activated radioactive substance which primarily emits alpha radiation, or some magical version. It's mostly harmless on the skin, causing light burns at worst, but when you hit it with an object and open the skin and expose blood to it, it causes massive damage as it floats through the body. By chance, this tends to cause about double the damage- e.g. if a person would normally take two gunshots to take down, they take one shot with slag.

Radioactivity damage is (a) non-steampunky and (b) has its immediately visible short-term damage accompagnied with a big long-term cancer risk. Also, radioactivity damage to too varied depending on how quickly the tissue regenerates, so you get a  really complicated damage model - or you're back at the starting point, the game mechanics does not match what the people of the world should observe.

Slag could be an exotic version of non-Newtonian oobleck that doesn't return to its liquid state after a high velocity impact and instead forms shards.
This goop could coat the target like a liquid and then shatter into shrapnel when struck causing extra damage.

Perhaps not from all types of Damage, but I can think of 3 types of examples where the properties of a substance drastically increase the amount of Damage taken without increasing the energy (then I will tie this all together):
1: Water and Explosive Damage.
Air is compressible, Water is not. Explosions that happen underwater have much more devastating blast waves compared to those in the air because of this factor. Although in Air you still get a positive/negative pressure wave, in Water this effect can be so destructive that if a structure (say a ships hull) survives the initial explosion, the subsequent forces can still tear it apart.
It is also for this reason that on some controlled demolitions, the explosive charges are surrounded by a Water jacket (also helps with noise, dust etc.)
2: Overpenetration.
Recent events provided an excellent example of this - whereby a full power rifle cartridge hitting one target (the top of someones ear) did very little overall damage - enabling an old man to stand up in defiance, whereas the same type of round fired moments later claimed the life of a Fire chief, Dad and Husband.
Both rounds had the same energy - but had vastly different effects on target. Which is in the first case, virtually none of the energy was dissapated into the target - the bullet whizzed by, taking a chunk of ear with it, but not really dumping that energy into the target. The second, hit a much more substantial target, slowed right down, putting all of that energy into the target, resulting in a fatality.
3: Endothermic substances that cause brittleness
This is probably going to be the use-case you use, as it is much more widely applicable than the other if the Slag itself takes energy out of the structure it is attached to, making it colder and therefore more brittle, then most attack types are going to be more effective (as the structure is weakened).
So to round it all up
There are two main ways this could work:
The first is by ensuring that the maximum amount of Energy is transferred to the target - in a lot of cases, energy is lost or not fully transferred into the target and that means that the theoretical maximum amount of damage is not achieved (The Water example and Overpenetration example)
The other is by having the Slag make the target structure more susceptible to damage - by weakening it.

Slag reverberates - a lot - in response to just about anything. It just doesn't absorb vibrations, it conducts vibrations instead
Like Vibranium, Slag can respond to vibrations from an impact; well, not all of the impact, you can still get through with enough force. You might think that would be pretty useful armour, except that it actually passes along the force that it "absorbs" and vibrates directly against the next thing around it.
What that means for the people who are wearing it? They feel the vibrations of the impact, then the impact itself, from anything that does damage to them. So they're feeling the same source of the pain almost as if it's an echo.

Slag weakens the bond between molecules
What are "things" (including people)?
Everything is made up from molecules. You, the steelbar and the wooden door. Also all three share the same state. They are solid. Soilds are molecules that bond together in semi-rigid structures and the properties of those bonds determine how "hard" the solid is.
What is "damage"?
Damage to a "thing" is the same as "making the thing come apart". Not neccessarily making a split but also a hole or a dent. So if we reduce it to the molecular level the "damage" means breaking up some bonds between molecules.
Steel and diamonds have stronger intermolecular bonds than flesh or paper making them harder to cut through, puncture, shatter, bend etc.
So what does slag? It weakens those bonds between molecules in solids. Thats why it doesn't have effect on liquids and gases as those already have quite weak bonds and weakening them further has little effect. Putting slag in water would probably reduce the surface tension of that water but not much more (don't drink it though, john did and his own bowl movements teared his guts apart, during disection we weren't able to discern the different organs anymore).
Slag on anything solid makes that solid easier to damage and destroy. Applying it to the foundations of a house or bridge might even be enough to make it break under it's own weight. Throwing a lump of it into your face before punching you makes a blow, that otherwise might have resulted in a black eye, break bones or tear open the skin leaving bleeding wounds instead.
Slight frame-challenge though:
The line of thinking "double damage" while talking out of game system is inherently flawed. There is no such thing as "twice the pain" or "dealing double the damage to a object". Two gunshot wounds don't hurt twice as much as one. And if they are close to each other you don't even lose twice as much blood. An axe strike against a door does not make it 25% "destroyed". It leaves a split that has a whole range of effects depending on multiple factors. And even if you would measure the damage to the object that way, it wouldn't mean that you need 4 such strikes to fully destroy the door.
Damage in real life does not work that way.
So nobody would say "lets put slag on the iron bars of our prison so I can deal double damage to it". They would simply say "lets put slag on the iron bars of our prison. That could weaken it enough to break them with this stick".
(Disclaimer: I know there is more to the strength of a material than just the hardness on molecular level but this is a neccessary simplyfication and just worrying about this one vector of material strength should suffice to explain the effects of slag)
In world implications of this answer
Putting slag on your weapons would be a bad idea. It would break when hitting your opponent because the slag weakens the weapon instead (I guess the slag would at least need a few seconds of contact to bring its effect to bear).
Instead you'd throw the slag onto your opponent and then strike them.
For storing and transporting slag I would think the people in the world would construct a multi layered container. The slag would only affect the inner container making it weaker. The outer container however would be unaffected and not break from getting shaken in a backpack. In between the two layers there would probably be a fluid like oil or water to absorb the shocks from impacts in order to keep the inner container intact.
If the container still breaks inside your backpack you'd probably want to throw all your food away and wash everything else throughly and check for damage. That is a interesting but not "game breaking" risk of carrying slag around.

Slag is alive but dumb. Maybe it is some magical entity, maybe a colony of microorganisms. If you hit something covered in slag, the slag gets hurt and defends itself/tries to feed itself on anything it covers.
If you throw some slaggy object at something covered in slag, the slag won't panick/get hurt, hence no double damage.
